# Retrieving XML Data - improve my approach

Tags: jquery

I'm retrieving xml data for google markers, however I also wanted the marker count too, so I did it like this.

```
<markers>
<results count="6" />
<marker id="1" lat="48.153938" lng="17.108459" icon_type="redicon" />
<marker id="2" lat="48.152657" lng="17.127541" icon_type="redicon" />
<marker id="3" lat="48.147572" lng="17.108433" icon_type="redicon" />
<marker id="14" lat="48.153938" lng="17.108459" icon_type="redicon" />
<marker id="15" lat="48.148170" lng="17.105650" icon_type="redicon" />
<marker id="16" lat="48.148170" lng="17.105650" icon_type="redicon" />
</markers>
```

Now, my markers retrieve post data like this, which works nicely:

```
success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
//lalalalala
```

Then I wanted to retrieve count and so I did this:

```
success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

$(data).find('markers').each(function(){
        var $entry = $(this);
        var pic = $entry.find('results').attr('count');
        $("#results").html(pic);
})

var xml = jqXHR.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");


for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
//lalala
```

However I'm sure there's a better way. Is there a way to combine what I did in the first instance with the markers to get the count as well? I just want to reduce the code in complexity.

Thanks!

Comment: If you just wanted to count, what was wrong with using markers.length directly?

Comment: Well, I'm not very experienced in jquery and I thought that markers.length counts only `<marker`. I did a lot of research on google and most of the articles there only explained xml formats `<something>content</something>`.

Comment: if the results count from the xml server has to be there, better access that directly than to count each element - I think I understand the situation pufAmuf please see my solution lmk if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the for loop instead perhaps, and iterate over the **markers** tag.

I have an example of this in action on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LyLR/

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("markers");

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

var currmarker = markers[i]
var markercount = currmarker.getElementsByTagName("results")[0].getAttribute("count");
//and whatever else you want to do

}
```

Comment: Thanks sajawikio, however by changing `markers[i].` to `currmarker.` I am unable to get any results. No errors show up, but no markers loaded either. Here is the code I made http://jsfiddle.net/4nMd7/

Comment: Your jsfiddle starts with success: function  - it does absolutely nothing! Also, jQuery is not included via the dropdown menu on the left (and even if it was, this code does nothing in your jsfiddle)

Comment: also look in my example jsfiddle - in jsfiddle u cant use XML documents - so its different in my Jsfiddle than it is in my answer - check it out.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to build a functional code, I just wanted to know if I can replace things such as `markers[i].getAttribute("id");` with `currmarker.getAttribute("id");`.

Comment: And as I see it looks like I can. Let me experiment a little :)